# Mandatory update for apps in windows store

Tags: windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I want my windows store app to update automatically even the user turn off the automatic update button in the settings (application update).

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: I hope not.  Store applications shouldn't be able to override the user's wishes.

Comment: ... of course your app could check whether an update is available, and refuse to run until it is installed.  (Personally I'd uninstall any such app pronto, and demand a refund, but YMMV.)

Answer (score 2):

Starting in Windows 10, version 1607, you can use an API in the [**Windows.Services.Store**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.services.store.aspx) namespace to programmatically check for package updates for the current app, and download and install the updated packages.

You can also query for packages that have been [**marked as mandatory on the Windows Dev Center dashboard**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/self-install-package-updates?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#mandatory-dashboard) and disable functionality in your app until the mandatory update is installed.

More info , you can refer to [**download and install package updates for your app**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/self-install-package-updates?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#mandatory-dashboard).